# Capture Web Service Request - Java

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, jax-ws, jax-rs

I have a web service that will act like a proxy for another service. It will capture the requests made of it, and forward them on to another service.

I need to do this because I need to interact with the underlying service using JMS. Right now, I'm trying to solve the first problem. How do I capture the request made of a Web service?

I need to implement the service interface with both JAX-RS 2.0 and JAX-WS as I need to capture both SOAP and REST requests.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the application server?

Comment: What do you mean "capture"? You want to dump it all to system.out or you need to intercept the request before it reaches a particular component?